# Why replacing sys.stdout breaks readlines facilities in 'pdb' or 'ipython'?

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, stdout, pdb

I would like to protect myself against encoding errors. A number of solutions will involve replacing `sys.stdout`, but this screws the recognition of arrow keys, and prevent nice editing of the current line or to call past commands in `pdb` or `ipython`. `Ctrl-R` also is broken. Deletion works. It seems that readline facilities are all gone or not triggered for some reasons.

Here's a simple example, that should be harmless as it simply passes its input without change to old `sys.stdout`:

```
cat <<EOF > /tmp/example.py

import sys

from codecs import StreamWriter

class TestWriter(StreamWriter):
    def write(self, obj):
        return self.stream.write(obj)

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  ## before replacing stdout, all works
sys.stdout = TestWriter(sys.stdout)  ## Type 'n' in pdb
pass                         ## 'pdb' shell is screwed up.
EOF
python /tmp/example.py
```

Nevertheless, this fails also. For some reasons this doesn't happen in python3, but only on python2.7.

What happens behind the scene ? Why is this failing ? Can this be avoided ?